# Residential MCB vs. Industrial MCB

Tags: circuit-breaker

Are there differences between residential circuit breaker and industrial circuit breaker? When I browse through various online catalogs on circuit breaker, ABB and Schneider Electrics are often labeled as "residential", but when I look up Eaton, they claim their circuit breaker to be "industrial". When I compare their specs, I cannot tell the difference.

I am planning to use a few MCB on a control panel, but not sure whether I should go with residential or industrial MCB...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They differ on current disconnection rating. A residential network has larger impedance comparing to the industrial network. This is due to the distance and size of the distribution transformer. When a short circuit is created on residential network it is rated about 6kA. In a big fabric, the transformer is usually placed inside the fabric a very large short circuit current is to be expected.

Comment: Industrial breakers are also normally rated for 480 to 600 VAC, and typically aren't designed to be plugged into a residential distribution panel.

Comment: @RDrast In our country, the residential and industrial voltage rating is the same 230/400VAC.  There is no network 480VAC or 600VAC. Also both types MCB can be installed on the same rail.

Comment: Would you please explain what is current disconnection rating? Do you mean industrial network has lower impedense and normally trip on higher current? If both are on the same voltage and trip current, it sounds to me residential MCB is more sensitive than industrial?

Comment: Industrial MCB's are rated for higher current tolerance; this what I presume from Marko's answer.

Comment: @KMC The trip current has nothing to do with breaking capacity current. A MCB rated for 10A trip current will 100% trip at 14A over a period of one hour. That would be an overload protection. But when you make a short circuit, the current would be \$I_{SC}=U_n/Z_n\$ , for example 15kA, and this is the current that your MCB has to disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

You must know the source fault level.  The supply is normally via a fault limiting breaker of about 250 A.  Close to this breaker high fault kA breakers are required and in a domestic dwelling, normally some distance away, 2.5 kA breakers might be adequate.

You have to understand the fault levels in all parts of the LV system to design the breaker kA rating correctly.  You can assume the MV fault level to be infinite as the main component reducing the fault current is the distribution transformer.

If the fault current is more than the circuit breaker rating, the circuit breaker can explode under fault conditions causing a lot of damage.  Fault currents of 20 kA to 100 kA are not unusual close to the supply transformer and that is as large as lightning, the MV fuse times are only 100 times longer than a lightning strike.  A large amount of energy is released in this flash, with the flash containing visible light and UV.  See this [65 kA 300 ms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltMv9MDSQaE) fault.

The fault MVA on the LV side is about the size in MVA/Zpu.  The cable impedance can be added to calculate the fault current at the end of the cable.

Answer (score 0):

The other unspoken aspect is that the term "residential" is relative to where the residence is. Here in the US, we do not use those IEC style MCBs for residential applications, we use a narrow format MCCB with a minimum fault capbility of 10kAIC (**k**ilo-**A**mps **I**nterrupting **C**apacity).

If you are using the MCBs in an industrial control panel application, the main thing you must pay attention to, as mentioned earlier, is the fault current rating. "Residential" versions of MCBs will be rated at 6 to 8kAIC, "industrial" versions will be 14 to 18kAIC. But even so, if you are planning on using these in the US, chances are that even 18kAIC will end up being woefully inadequate for any voltage over 240V. Rules here for Industrial Control Panels in the National Electric Code now require what's called an SCCR (Short Circuit Current Rating) for the overall assembly, then the rules on that state that the maximum SCCR is limited to the lowest rated component in the panel. So if you use an MCB rated for 18kAIC, you cannot possibly apply an SCCR of greater than 18kA, which means end users will be ***unable to connect it*** (legally) to a system capable of more than that amount of fault current. Without going into all the gory details of how that is calculated, a simple chart engineering method will tell you that the end user will be limited to a 75kVA supply transformer at 208V 3 phase, or a 150kVA transformer at 480V 3 phase. Most industrial facilities will be MUCH larger than that.

Then also if you ARE using them at 480V, those IEC MCB devices have a further restriction in North America in that the ones labeled at 480V are limited to use on 480Y277 *solidly grounded neutral* supplies. A lot of industrial applications in North America are 480V delta systems, so those breakers cannot be used at all. The safe bet, if you cannot know in advance WHERE your control panel is going to end up, is to NOT use MCBs in them.